# AWK Beginner, What happens in this code?

Tags: awk, signature

I have seen several variations of this awk code (people have re-written it to show their own email address) and I can't understand what is going on here. Can someone break it down (perhaps to a smaller example) for me please?

http://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/html_node/Signature-Program.html

Code;

```
awk 'BEGIN{O="~"~"~";o="=="=="==";o+=+o;x=O""O;while(X++<=x+o+o)c=c"%c";
     printf c,(x-O)*(x-O),x*(x-o)-o,x*(x-O)+x-O-o,+x*(x-O)-x+o,X*(o*o+O)+x-O,
     X*(X-x)-o*o,(x+X)*o*o+o,x*(X-x)-O-O,x-O+(O+o+X+x)*(o+O),X*X-X*(x-O)-x+O,
     O+X*(o*(o+O)+O),+x+O+X*o,x*(x-o),(o+X+x)*o*o-(x-O-O),O+(X-x)*(X+O),x-O}'
```

Outputs;

```
dave_br@gmx.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the magic lies in the printf statement.  This is from the awk man page:

> The AWK versions of the printf statement and sprintf() function (see below) accept
>   the following conversion specification formats:
>
> `%c`
>
> An ASCII character. If the argument used for `%c` is numeric, it is
>   treated as a character and printed. Otherwise, the argument is assumed to be a
>   string, and only the first character of that string is printed.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction! That was the nudge I needed, I have written my own now :D